# Fabric JS - Text clipping outside the custom boundary while moving, scaling and rotating

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to do text clipping outside the boundary while moving/scaling/rotating.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I tried with this example http://jsfiddle.net/45zng4ge/.  its working while moving.  After rtating, its not working.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I tried your fiddle and the clipping is the same before/while/after moving, and before/while/after rotating.